# The theory of dense linear orderings without endpoints is not $\lambda$ categorical for any uncountable $\lambda$.

Tags: logic, order-theory, model-theory

I am trying to prove the statement of the question.
The only strategy that comes to my mind is to exploit the theorem of Morley saying that if a theory (in a countable language) is $\lambda$ categorical for an uncountable cardinal then it is $\lambda$ categorical for *any* uncountable cardinal.
Then it suffices to show, for instance that the real and the irrational numbers, seen as DLO are not isomorphic, like in [The theory of dense linear orders without end-points is not $2^\omega$-categorical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057263/the-theory-of-dense-linear-orders-without-end-points-is-not-2-omega-categoric).
I have also seen proofs based on the notion of stable theory.

But is it there a simpler proof which avoids the theorem of Morley and the notion of stable theory (which we have not treated in the course where the excercise was proposed)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given an uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ consider the linear order $\leq_1$ obtained by replacing every element of $\kappa$ with a copy of $\Bbb Q$, and the linear order $\leq_2$ obtained by replacing every element of $\kappa^\ast$ ($\kappa$ with the reverse order) by a copy of $\Bbb Q$.

Explicitely the first order is $\kappa\times\Bbb Q$ where $(\alpha,q)<_1(\beta,p)$ iff $\alpha<\beta$ or $\alpha=\beta$ and $p<q$, while the second is $\kappa\times\Bbb Q$ where $(\alpha,q)<_1(\beta,p)$ iff $\beta<\alpha$ or $\beta=\alpha$ and $p<q$.

Those are both dense linear orders of cardinality $\kappa$ without endpoints, do you see why they are not isomorphic? Hint: does $\omega_1$ embed into both?

Comment: Can you express in first-order logic in this theory that statement that $\omega_1$ embeds into the model?

Comment: @RobertShore This is impossible; if were, the same formula also works over some  countable structure by Löwenheim-Skolem theorem.

Comment: @RobertShore No, the point is that these two models are elementarily equivalent (they satisfy the same complete theory - the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints) but not isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am non fully sure about what it means to replace each point of k or k* by Q. Are you implying that we end with something like two lexicographic orders ?

Comment: I wrote it explicitely, it is a lexicographic product

Comment: Thanks again: it was actually clear from your previous answer, but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks.  My model theory days were a long time ago so I'd forgotten there's a difference between elementarily equivalent and isomorphic.